# Access coordinates from the parent of a widget

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have a `QGraphicsView` inside the `MainWindow` that has implemented a `QGraphicScene`. I need to pop up a widget when I right click the mouse on a certain portion of the `QGraphicScene`. The parent of the widget needs to be `MainWindow`.

My problem is that I need to verify the validity of the portion on witch I clicked inside a `mousePressEvent` in `QGraphicScene` and to pop up the widget at the exact same location but the coordinates of the `QGraphicScene` and `MainWindow` are obvious not the same. For that I use a custom signal that trigger a slot inside `MainWindow` and get the coordinates from the `mousePressEvent` of the `MainWindow`. The problem is that the `mouseEvent` from the `QGraphicsScene` is triggered before the `mouseEvent` from `MainWindow`. This makes perfect sense and works if I right click twice but I need it to work from the first right click.

I can not implement a filter or change the focus because I have tons of events in the application.

QGraphicScene:

```
void CGraphicScene :: mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event -> button() == Qt::RightButton)
    {
        //test stuff

        emit signalChangeContextualMenuPosition();
        m_contextualMenu -> show();
    }
}
```

MainWindow:

```
    CGraphicScene *scene;
    CContextualMenu *m_contextualMenu;
    m_contextualMenu = new CContextualMenu(this);
    m_contextualMenu ->close();
    scene = new CGraphicScene(m_contextualMenu);

    ui->gvInterface -> setScene(scene);
    connect(scene, SIGNAL(signalChangeContextualMenuPosition()), this, SLOT(openPopUp()));

    void MainWindow :: openPopUp()
    {
         m_contextualMenu ->move(m_xCoordPopMenu, m_yCoordPopMenu);
    }

    void MainWindow :: mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
    {
        if(event -> button() == Qt::RightButton)
        {
            m_xCoordPopMenu = event -> x();
            m_yCoordPopMenu = event -> y();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `QGraphicsView::mapFromScene()` to map scene coordinates to the view widget coordinates and then `QWidget::mapToParent()` to map the coordinates to it's parent widget, which is probably your main window. You can also find useful the method `QWidget::mapTo()`.

Comment: This is a very nice solution. I manage to send the point where I wish to pop up the widget with a signal to the MainWindow. There I used mapFromScene on the QGraphicsView with that point.